Szemeredi Regularity Lemma - Reasonable Bounds
Recently, I came across the wonderful Szemeredi regularity lemma and I was wondering.  Are these "natural/reasonable/standard" examples of random graphs families, for which the number of $\varepsilon$-regular parts in the Szemeredi lemma is grows like $O(\varepsilon^{-r})$ for some $r>0$.  Or are the only available bounds always power towers in $\varepsilon$?

I imagine for random graphs you only need very few parts with high probability — after all, the condition of regularity is an approximation of being random. The main strength of the regularity lemma is that it works for all graphs

@Command Master Exactly what I expected, but still I cannot find a formal statement where one gets nice bounds.

Malliaris and Shelah have shown that the number of parts needed grows only like $\epsilon^{-r}$ it $G$ doesn't contain half-graphs of size $O(\log r)$. See, for example, https://shelah.logic.at/files/217705/notes_on_the_stable_regularity_lemma.pdf
